# Discovering repositories of ANY type

Tags: git, svn, version-control, repository

**Backstory:** We acquired the IP (Intellectual Property) rights to a company <strike>going</strike> gone out of business. This company mainly produced semiconductor manufacturing/testing equipment, but they also had to write their own software to interface with the robot's controller, which ran on a Windows 2000 PC.

With the acquisition of the IP we now control the "Source Code" of this software, which was given to us on about 5 separate external HDD's, which we plan on continuing development on.

Now I've only used Hg and Git repositories before, and have only heard of others like Subversion (SVN) and CVS.

With Mercurial I know all the files needed for the "repository" were simply stored in a folder called .hg but I am aware older systems relied on a Server-Client model.

**Goal:** My goal here is to find any and all repositories that exist on these drives.

**Challenge:** That is the extent of what I know. I will not be the one continuing development, I'm the one who will be setting up the system for the engineer(s) who will be, so I'm not exactly sure what I'll be looking at. I have no knowledge of what type of system they were using to manage development of this code. The company went bankrupt years back so most of the employees who worked directly with it are working at other companies now. I *can* tell you most of the work was done in the 90's, early 2000's so it's more likely than not to be an older-type system.

**Scenario:** I have a drive connected to my laptop. I can search it any way I want – I just don't know exactly what I'm searching for, or even if I've found it. I can download the appropriate software and learn how to open a repository with it using these system's existing documentations, if I knew what system I'm looking at first. What kind of file, folder structure patterns should I look for to identify if a certain type of repository is present? What should I search for? Any alternate methods of discovery?

*I can post results of my searches in the comments.*

***Current finds:***

- Folder named "04 WW rst and cvs files"
- Folder named "SVN"
- Files named "*.svn-base", "hrsvn.sso", "hrsvn.ssl", "WSVNS.H"

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_version_control_software or **hire good sysadmin** for good bucks in Real World

Comment: Yes, I have been using that list thus far to get where I am, ty. What I am asking for is what kind of naming conventions are used? I just need someone familiar with the old systems. Commonly used terms would be helpful, so would known structures, file extensions, etc. The Wikipedia list does not differentiate which systems were widely used and which are rare, and I can't access the proprietary systems. This info is not easily accessible in the documentation either. I can certainly handle the rest, if someone who knew could just point me in the right direction. Ty.

Answer (score 0):

In the index of all file paths these drives contain, searching "subversion" returned 6898 results.

Closer inspection shows that in users folders, almost every user had TortoiseSVN and Visual Studio 2005 installed.

That is all I needed to continue making our development environment. I don't know Visual Studio, but I don't have to. All I need to do is make it available for our engineers.

I still have no idea "where" the svn repositories are, but this answers my question: they were using 'subversion'. Now my next q can be much more specific: how to find a svn repository in that inherited mess of files, and I bet there's already plenty of existing documentation on that. If not, there soon will be.

For those inheriting a mess:

- **Apache Subversion** (SVN, TortoiseSVN, .svn)
- **Mercurial** (.hg, TortoiseHg)
- **Git** (.git)
- **Visual Source Safe** (VSS)

Those are, in no particular order, the most commonly used repositories for source code control. That comes from nothing more than my personal expeirence with the subject thus far.

PROTIP: If you can get access to users' Program Files, check out what software they have installed. It will help.

Comment: "how to find a svn repository in that inherited mess of files" it's easy: just install *any* SVN-client (better - the same|compatible version, which was used originally - check number in `.svn\format` file) and `svn info` inside **any** part of Working Copy (BTW, TSVN with icon overlays will help to identify WC's easy) contain as part of output "Repository Root"

Comment: Thank you! Edited answer for new info. This puts me on the right track.